# I am getting random behaviour in the session variable while storing in the session array

Tags: php, session

i have these session arrays that is used to store IDs.

$_SESSION['bID'] is used for insert query

$_SESSION['rmbID'] is used for delete query

the below arrays are created on action via ajax and stored in the session variable 
i have copied the array from error_log file.

```
[bID] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 9
        [3] => 20
        [5] => 23
        [6] => 25
    )

[rmbID] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 22
        [3] => 4
    )
```

1.column live_boxes(on left)

2.column remaining_boxes(on right side)

**for insert :**

what i to do is if i drag the box from 2nd column and drop it in 1st column then $_SESSION['bID'] should hold the ID = 5(suppose) in its session array $_SESSION['bID']

and if that ID = 5 is already present in rmbID's i.e $_SESSION['bID'] array then it should be removed.

**for delete :**
vise verse.

my code for the same is 
**for adding in bID's session and removing from rmbID's session**

```
array_push($_SESSION['bID'],$_GET['bID']);
                    if (isset($_SESSION['rmbID']) && in_array($_GET['bID'], $_SESSION['rmbID']))
                    {
                        unset($_SESSION['rmbID'][array_search($_GET['bID'],$_SESSION['rmbID'])]);
                        //console.log('add');
                    }
```

**for adding in rmbID's session and removing from bID's session**

```
array_push($_SESSION['rmbID'],$_GET['rmbID']);
                    if (isset($_SESSION['bID']) && in_array($_GET['rmbID'], $_SESSION['bID']))
                    {
                        unset($_SESSION['bID'][array_search($_GET['rmbID'],$_SESSION['bID'])]);
                        //console.log('remove');
                    }
```

What i want is that the session should store values properly and remove values properly.

Comment: in your question you mention `$_SESSION['rmbID']` yet in your code you are using `$_GET['rmbID']` ?

Comment: i am using ajax to pass this value via get method and store it in session.

Comment: nobody knows or what????